# Get a given day from Calendar instance

Tags: android

Suppose I have a date like 01/01/2012 and I want to see what day it is, how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425472/using-date-functions-in-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using SimpleDateFormate object we can get the date from string date:

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
        try {  
            Date date = format.parse("01/01/2012");  
            switch(date.getDay()) {
            case 0: "sunday";
            break;
            case 1: "monday";
            break;
            ....
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have date as string. In that case you should first parse the date using SimpleDateFormat and then get the day of week from that date using [Date.getDay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29).

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
int day = dateObj.getDay();
```